# Inclination of planets

Tags: orbital-motion, planets, sun, solar-system

What is the inclination of each planet with the equator of the Sun? Doesn't this have a relationship with the eccentricity of the planet's orbit?

Comment: The first half of your question can be easily answered with a quick google search.  The second half your question could be a more interesting question, though.

Answer (score 0):

A great amount of planetary data is available [at this NASA website.](http://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/planetary/factsheet/) There doesn't appear to be a strong correlation, but you could use this NASA data to do the statistics.